# Azure Kubernetes Nodeport

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

Does NodePort service work in azure kubernetes ?

My use case is , I'm trying to deploy 3 Nodes (3 VMs) , such that every node has a pod which runs an nginx container, using daemonsets.
So 3 nodes -> 3 pods -> 3 docker nginx containers running basic welcome to nginx page.

Now to expose the service, I use load balancer and get a public IP which runs any of the three pods and when i do
http:// ----> it displays welcome to nginx page using one of the pods.

Now i want to deploy NodePort, so that i can view my nginx page using
http://:nodeport

I'm not able to access this using node public IP and i'm using azure kubernetes service.

What to do next

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30007
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

Comment: you can run and check the service endpoint first `kubectl get endpoints`

Comment: what error are you seeing and did you tried curl, traceroute? check the port is not getting blocked anywhere.

Comment: It might just be that nodePort: 30007 is not accessible from your IP. What's the result if you do curl "http://:nodeport" from within the node?

Comment: My bad. I forgot to open port. Thanks @rock'nrolla

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-multiple-node-pools#assign-a-public-ip-per-node-in-a-node-pool

Comment: @jhanvishah Glad to know you have it working now. Please post what worked for you as an answer below so it helps others in the community as well.

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara the same solution worked for me. On azure, I went inside azure node pool which had one node pool with three virtual machines, as per my requirement. I opened ports for that node pool , so that all virtual machines inside that pool has those ports opened(in my case - only 30007) and it worked like a charm.